# Possible to set :hover to a certain class instead of specific css properties?

Tags: css

I have a class as follows:

```
.X { color: #123456; background-color:#987654 }
```

Is it possible to do the following without using scripting code?

```
a:hover {
  //set css to all in class X
  //color: the color specified in class X
  //background-color: the color specified in class X
}
```

Comment: I don't think so, but you could use css variables https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so but you could include both the element and the class like so:

```
a.X:hover
p.X:hover
h1.X:hover
...
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

What you might be looking for is use a css preprocessor like SASS, in which you do exactly what you ask, you define a class .X and then inside an element you *extend* that class using `@extend .X`

You should look into it!